# Is there any cross-browser css-only sticky footer with W3C valid css and semantic X/HTML?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, cross-browser

Is there any cross-browser css sticky footer with W3C valid css and semantic X/HTML?

IE : 6,7,8

Firefox : All Version

Safari: Windows, Mac and iPHONE

Opera: Windows, Mobile and Mini

Google Chrome : All Version

Blackberry Browser

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this one and it works well in FF, IE, Safari, Opera, and Chrome. Don't know about Blackberry: [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)